# Delete a member of a class in destructor which is made by new in a method in C++

Tags: class, destructor, new-operator, member, delete-operator

I searched this question but I couldn't find it, if it's a repeated question without giving negative point tell me the link of answer.

In the **Student** class I have lots of members but four of them is created by the operator **new** in a method public which called **set**

I write only one of them here:

```
class Student{
   private:
     float *tp;
   ....
}
```

Here is the method **set** which is **public**:

```
void Student::set(int field, int valeur){
    ...
            tp = new float[valeur];
    ...     
}
```

Here is **destructor** which is **public**:

```
    ~Student(){
        ...
        delete tp;
        ...
    }
```

The **main**:

```
...
Student *students=new Student[n];
...
delete students;
```

There is not any error during compiling but when I run I faced the error:

I change also the **main** code just for checking like:

```
    Student s;
```

The error exist yet.

[image]

Comment: There's a mistake in the code that you didn't post

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete code sample that exhibits this problem

Comment: in what you included, you don't call `set` and therefore `tp` may have an indeterminate value causing `delete tp` to have undefined behaviour

Comment: you should also use `delete[]` when deleting arrays

Comment: [vu1p3n0x](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/vu1p3n0x) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Az [vu1p3n0x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/vu1p3n0x) said:

if I used new [] I should use delete [].

Thank you [vu1p3n0x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/vu1p3n0x)

Comment: glad I could help :D